# Create Lookup + Calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I've an issue on calculating lookup value from other list.. I have List called "Product". in that I have column name "ProductCode"(Single line text) and "Unit Price"(number with 2 decimal). I've created a new custom list called "Purchase Form".

In that "Purchase Form" I want to have below:

- A auto sequence column "Purchase ID" which will auto generate as "PO-15-####". The behind number will start from 2001.
- A lookup column of "ProductCode" which will be in Choice mode.
- A column which have "Unit Price" from another list will automatically generated when we choose the "ProductCode".
- The main important column is "Purchased Value" which will calculate [Purchased Qty*Unit Price] and results will be in currency or number. [I will another column called "Purchased Qty"(number).]

I've tried lookup but unable to do the calculate. I need to have a workaround without using any backend commands.

Please help me to guide how to do in SharePoint 2013 or InfoPath 2013 without having workflow involved.

Comment: is javascript allowed?

Comment: How do I check on that? This is my company test site for me to play around and learn more on SharePoint 2013. Please assist.

Comment: Generally there's no restriction on using client side scripting, though you ll need to check. Why workflows not allowed. Very strange.

Comment: How to do by using workflow? I've never done any workflow before. Please guide on achieving the goal.

Comment: @TaranGoel: Can you help me with this?

Comment: @TaranGoel: Can we do it with InfoPath and How we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Order to achieve your goal workflows are  required. you can't calculate the lookup fields, so you need to copy the lookup field into a single line of text using "Set" value in workflow, do the same for other columns which are unable to calculate. finally after creating all single line of texts you can keep a column for calculated values and get your workdone.

Comment: It can be done without Workflows but requires all the logic to be done with JavaScript code... not for beginners.

Comment: How it can be done by using workflow? I've never touched workflow part. Please guide.